# Should I store duplicate email addresses?

Tags: node.js, authentication, registration

Just thinking about my registration flow for my Nodejs/MongoDB app and wondered whether I really need to check if email addresses are already in the database when users register.

I make my users verify their email address by clicking on an email that I will send to them. They must do this before logging in at all. Once they do click on this link then I will mark that email as `verified` in the database. With this in mind, I'm thinking that it doesn't really matter if someone registers with the same email address (for whatever reason) as it won't be marked as `verified` unless they can access the email account.

I'm wondering however if it will impact on performance when it comes to searching for users in the database via email address. For example, users login using email address. Would it be advisable in this case to create an index on both `email` and `verified`?

Have I overlooked something that could potentially be a security flaw?

Answer (score 0):

Performance-wise it will probably not matter a great deal (you probably already have an index on the `email` field), but I don't think you should allow it anyway.

For one, it has the potential to add junk to your database. Secondly, it would allow existing users to create—by mistake or not—a second account  with the same e-mail address, which could cause all sorts of issues.

You don't give a specific reason for wanting to allow duplicate e-mail addresses, but a duplicate check isn't really all that time-consuming to implement (you could also consider a unique index on `email` so the database will throw an error when someone is trying to reregister an existing address).

Comment: Some interesting points, thanks - Users wouldn't be able to create a second account because if the email address is verified then the email won't be able to be registered. With regards the "junk" issue I think this is always going to be a problem. I could also clear out accounts that haven't been verified within a certain time. One reason for my approach is that it stops people/machine registering an email that isn't theirs and stopping other users.

Comment: @tommyd456 if that's your concern, you could allow people that are trying to register a "pending" address (one that has been registered but hasn't been verified yet) to ask for the confirmation e-mail to be sent again.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by `verified` in my question. So you don't think there will be a performance issue with a large number of users?

Comment: @tommyd456 if you have your indexes set up properly, running a query for a single e-mail address will probably not yield more than a few records (_if_ you would allow duplicate addresses being registered). If we're talking about millions of users then you should probably consider minimizing the amount of "junk" in the database. Still, I would probably set up a _unique_ index on `email` myself.